# Break Python Functions into Other Files

Tags: python

So to keep it simple I just want to be able to reference the function in C from A and I'm not sure how to do this in python without directly referencing c which I don't want to do

```
a.py references b.py
b.py references c.py

c.py has a function in it called foo
```

I want to call foo from a.py but for abstraction purposes I want to only reference b.py

I tried to set up a simple example like the one above before I start attempting this on my actual codebase but it seems I can't see the member in C from A

Comment: How do you import the functions now? In `b.py`: `from c import foo`, and then in `a.py`: `from b import foo` should work.

Comment: I don't doubt that'd work @tobias_k but I'm not trying to have to import every member individually. The b.py file in real life is going to get broken out into maybe 10 or more sub files which all have 5-10 functions in each

Comment: You should import everything you need individually. That's how imports are supposed to be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So not the most ideal solution but it appears if I create a member for each sub file in b.py it will allow me to access it from a.py

It would look something like this

c.py

```
def call_me_c():
    print("It works from c")
```

b.py

```
import c
cfile = c
```

a.py

```
import b
b.cfile.call_me_c()
```

Comment: That `cFile = c` is not needed, you can just do `b.c.call_me_c()`. Just doing `import c` (or `from c import foo` or `import c as cFile` or `from c import foo as whatever`) will make this a name in `b` that can then be used in `a` after `import b` or `from b import thatname`.

Comment: @tobias_k thank you. If you make that an answer I'll accept it as soon as it lets me